# laravel 4: relation seems to not be working more than once

Tags: laravel, relational-database, laravel-4

I have a User model that has a one to many relation with the Status model. And in my code, the first time I call the `User::find()->status;` everything is great, but later when I find all the user's friends and look for their statuses, it gives me empty arrays even though I know the statuses are there. I'm new to relations and laravel in general, so I think I'm looking over something simple. Any help and related reading(not the docs) would be appreciated!
The problem code is:

```
 $status = array();
    $status[] = User::find(Auth::user()->id)->status;
    $friends = User::find(Auth::user()->id)->friend;
    $users = array();
    foreach($friends as $f){
        $users[] = User::find($f->friend_id)->friend;
    }
    foreach($users as $u){
        $status[] = $u->status; // this line is the issue
    }
    $data['status'] = $status;
return View::make('index.index', $data);
```

Edit:
The tables look as:

```
user                friends              status
//////////////////   ////////////////    ////////////////
// id           //   // id         //    // id         //
// email        //   // user_id    //    // user_id    //
// password     //   // friend_id  //    // status     //
// first_name   //   // confirmed  //    // created_at //
// last_name    //   // created_at //    // updated_at //
// created_at   //   // updated_at //    ////////////////
// updated_at   //   ////////////////
//////////////////
```

Comment: Are you sure that you have built the right relations? Or if the user has friends?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your relations may not be set correctly.

The way you should be using Eloquent to model the relations is this:

```
class User extends Eloquent
{
   public function friends()
   {
         return $this->belongsToMany('User', 'users_friends', 'user_id', 'friend_id');
   }

   public function statuses()
   {
        return $this->hasMany('Status');
   }
}
```

And then you can use the code like this:

```
$user = User::find(Auth::user()->id);
$friends = $user->friends;
$statuses = $user->statuses;

$friends_statuses = array();

foreach($friends as $friend)
{
   $friends_statuses = array_merge($friends_statuses, $friend->statuses);
}
```

Comment: I think that is on the right track, but isn't quite working, I added the table structures to make sure we're on the same page. Also, I was under the impression that belongstoMany() only takes 2 arguments, where can I find documentation about the other arguments?

Comment: Check here: http://four.laravel.com/docs/eloquent under this title: Many To Many. where it is explained how associated keys can be overwritten.